# $.fn.myPlugin vs $.something.myPlugin in regard to private and public methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, private-methods, public-method

So I can't seem to find  astraight answer on this, only vague examples of multiple variations where similar plugin/method declarations are used. I know that by saying

```
$.fn.myPlugin
```

I am defining a publicly available plugin method that can be executed on any valid jQuery object where the fn denotes the prototype. My question is then, by defining a method, either inside of my main plugin like so

```
$.fn.myPlugin.methodName
```

or outside of my plugin like so

```
$.something.methodName //where 'something' is in place of 'fn'
```

does this affect it being a public private/method? and if each is a different type of declaration, what is the difference.

The backstory of why I would like to know, to give some context to the situation, is that I want to define one main plugin that can be called and have run normally, however if the end user wants to redefine some method I have allowed to be public then they can do that. If I have any methods that I don't want the user to redefine but instead provide callbacks so they can hook into it, then I want to make that method private.

Comment: If you're setting anything on `$.whatever`, then it's public...

Comment: so would I then do `$.fn.myPlugin.privateMethod` to declare a private method for myPlugin?

Comment: No.  You can't create private methods in public scope like that.  Look at the answer provided by @NiettheDarkAbsol below to see how to do it.

Comment: Yea I just saw it pop up after posting that last comment, explains it perfectly. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything set on `$.whatever` will be public, and therefore able to be modified by other developers.

If you want private methods, you should create a closure.

```
(function() {
    function init(jqObj) { ... } // do magic here
    $.fn.myPlugin = function() { init(this); } // avoid exposing core method
    $.fn.myPlugin.publicMethod = function() { ... }
    function privateMethod() { ... }
})();
```

Comment: ahhh okay, that makes sense. I do have closure being defined via `(function($) {  }(jQuery));` I see now that private methods are just locally scoped functions. That is the piece I was missing, however, are you using the `function(init)` as a private function of the main plugin as to avoid anyone over writing the plugin itself?